# Is there a way to make text in the interface sharper like Windows?

Tags: fonts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make fonts look good in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/897/how-can-i-make-fonts-look-good-in-ubuntu)

I noticed on every install of Ubuntu, the font is softer than on Windows. Is this a setting somewhere?

Comment: Exact duplicate of that question, with slightly different wording but identical answers.

Answer (score 1):

In System->Preferences->Appearance you can go to the Font tab and change the Hinting to get a different look. Don't remember which one is closest to Windows style but I believe it's full hinting.

Comment: Also make sure the resolution is set to 96dpi, it makes a huge difference for some fonts.

Answer (score 1):

System -> Preferences -> Appearance -> Fonts -> Details.
There you can play with various font smoothing settings to make it look good for you. But it'll never be the same as in Windows, technologies used are much different.

Joel Spolsky [had something](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2007/06/12.html) to say on the topic. It's about Mac and Windows but the way Linux do font rendering is much closer to what Mac does.