# How to get accurate and clear font display?

Tags: fonts, font-rendering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make fonts look good?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/897/how-can-i-make-fonts-look-good)

The setting I liked until now is *subpixel + 0 hinting*.

Any better idead?

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/897/how-can-i-make-fonts-look-good

Answer (score 0):

This works for me... But your display may differ.

[image]

If you're still having issues, check you're using the native display resolution. If you don't, it'll be stretching the fonts out.