# Screen text is blurry / fuzzy

Tags: ati, fonts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make fonts look like they do in Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/897/how-can-i-make-fonts-look-like-they-do-in-windows)

Coming from Win XP.
Trying **Ubuntu 11.04 / Gnome Classic UI**,
and *LOVE IT!*

Only real problem I have:

Under Win XP, the text on the screen
and inside any prog.,
  is always CRISP and easy to read.

But in Ubuntu, 
the screen text looks slightly blurred (fuzzy), hard to read -
not crisp & clear, as in XP...
for ANY prog. (Firefox, gedit, you name it).

Tried:
    System > Preferences > Appearance > Fonts > Details
and played with Smoothing & Hinting options, 
and also tried different Fonts listed there.

Result: 
   only *marginally* better, but *still* fuzzy text.

(btw: *same blurry text* when I tried *Linux Mint 11*
      and *Linux Mint 11 LXDE* distros).

My assumption:
   I'm not a hardware nor systems guy,
but I suspect that Ubuntu 11.04 
and my Graphics card (*ATI Radeon X1300PRO 256MB ram*),
don't play nice together.

- Anyone out there has experience with any incompatibility of *ATI Radeon X1300PRO* graphic cards with Ubuntu? (and what to do about it...).
- An ATI driver issue, or maybe another issue / solution?

Thanks for any pointers / fixes!.

- DELL Optiplex 745 desktop w/ 2GB RAM
- ATI Radeon X1300PRO 256MB ram
- LG 1953H LCD - 19 inch monitor

Comment: A picture would help alot here.

Comment: Thanks Jorge, for the quick response & link. Will try following the instructions & tips
in: **"How can I make fonts look like they do in Windows?"** http://askubuntu.com/questions/897/how-can-i-make-fonts-look-like-they-do-in-windows Will report any results in this thread, later.