# Ubuntu 11.10 Blurry Fonts

Tags: 11.10, fonts, antialiasing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make fonts look like they do in Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/897/how-can-i-make-fonts-look-like-they-do-in-windows)

I'm very new to Linux as in I've only been using it for about a week. My problem is  fonts are incredibly blurry and it's very difficult to read long periods of time. I've tried to change `fonts.conf` file and added this:

```
![<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
 <match target="font" >
  <edit mode="assign" name="autohint" >
   <bool>true</bool>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <match target="font" >
  <edit mode="assign" name="rgba" >
   <const>none</const>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <match target="font" >
  <edit mode="assign" name="hinting" >
   <bool>false</bool>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <match target="font" >
  <edit mode="assign" name="hintstyle" >
   <const>hintnone</const>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <match target="font" >
  <edit mode="assign" name="antialias" >
   <bool>true</bool>
  </edit>
 </match>
</fontconfig>]
```

I also tried to use gnome tweak tool  but hinting/ Anti-aliasing doesn't have any effect on browsers Chrome/Chromium/Firefox.

The methods I mentioned made some differences but the problem still exists, is there a way to get rid of this blurry effect or am I doomed for eternity?

Thank you so much for your help!

**Windows 7:**

[image]

**Ubuntu 11.10:**

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/897/18612

Comment: I cannot see a problem in your screenshot. So maybe the problem is not the font, but the way, the image is rendered on the screen. If you have a flat screen you might have chosen an unsupported resolution in Ubunut. You should choose the native resolution of your display. You can have a look at the resolution you selected in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

The default Sans font, is Ugly, imho.
The Arial, Tribuchet MS and some other MS fonts, don't render properly, Tribuchet MS has a problem with e. An extra line on top. I hate it.

The good windows fonts Tahoma, Segoe, Callbiri, Cambria all render poorly, due to lack of cleartype.

Trying to use this xml, in .fonts.conf that is supposed to magically make rendering smooth, does nothing more than turn on sub pixel smoothing.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd"> <fontconfig> <match target="font"> <edit name="autohint" mode="assign"> <bool>true</bool> </edit> </match> </fontconfig>
```

Turning on sub-pixel smoothing makes the font bold at the cost of clear shapes, it is a turn off. The otherwise awesome Monospace font also looks bad.

What is the best font I can have on my Ubuntu system. It is alright if it is commercial and expensive. I could do with better font typefaces.

[source](https://superuser.com/questions/19824/better-ubuntu-fonts)