# How can I get the browser to render font exactly like Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, fonts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make fonts look like they do in Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/897/how-can-i-make-fonts-look-like-they-do-in-windows)

I don't like the small fonts in the browser. However, increasing the size causes trouble; the last word in a sentence will start a new line. This is really ugly.

I want the exact same font rendering in the browser as in Windows 7 (pixel for pixel) because web pages are made for it. It is the right size and has the right number of pixels between letters and so on (yes, i am picky).

If possible, anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Pixel by pixel exact same rendering? Nope, not possible. And if it were, it would likely be in violation of patents regarding e.g. Microsoft ClearType, the "new" (since XP or something) font rendering techniques especially tailored for LCDs.

You can, however, get as close as possible by:

- using the exact same browser version and settings on both systems;
- installing your Windows fonts on your Linux system; and
- playing around with the level of anti-aliasing etc. offered to you by either GUI tools or by manually editing your `fonts.conf` file.

Or if you are truly repulsed by the font rendering in mainly the browser, see if the Windows version gives you good results when you run it using Wine.